# Recommendation for asp.net mvc SPA

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I currently have visual studio 2010 and want some advice on the best way to utilise a single page application. I have used ExtJs before which works well, however i wanted to know if there are any frameworks out there now that people would recommend? It's for a cockpit to display statistical data and display charts etc..

Comment: Angular 2 is on the way. Release is planned on late 2015. If you start new app, I'd recommend to take a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Choosing your IDE

First, you said that you currently have VS2010.

I have to ask: can't you get VS2015 (preview) up and running? It's free and once it's released you should be able to get it with some MSDN subscription or (if that feels too expensive for you) with MS Registered Partner + MAPS subscription (which also includes Windows and Office for you).

If you really can't, that's OK. You can do all that I'll say with VS2010. But VS2015 makes it really easy to work with these technologies.

#### Choosing your server-side platform

You want to create a single-page website/application. That's good. You're on the right track to modern apps. But that's about client-side, not server-side.

To make thinks simple here, you might choose from MVC or WebAPI. Of course there are other alternatives, including WebForms, PHP, etc, but I'm guessing you want to make things really clean and fast, so you have these two modern frameworks to choose.

For the sake of this answer (it's a very simplistic and is missing many things) Asp.net MVC is about Razor and views, while WebAPI is about REST and Json.

You can mix both, serve Razor from WebApi and send Json from MVC, but my choice here is to use WebAPI to force you resolve everything using REST calls, Json and plain HTML files. You'll see why.

#### Choosing your client-side framework

There are many options out there to help you with SPA.

I like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) the most. It's simple, it works, it's created and used by Google (so it must work, period) it's multi-browser-compatile and has many HTML5 plugins that you can use (with fallback to other methods, like cookies).

Angular will help you with a base JavaScript app and modules to create a composite app, with MVC in mind. You won't really need jQuery anymore unless you're doing something really complex. Also, Angular helps you prevent leaks and become more and more async, which is good for modern apps.

Also, Angular will help you with bindings and HTML generation. So, actually, you won't really use Razor unless on a very ultimate-specific-complex case. You'll send a template HTML with some markup that Angular will render with some Json or some specific directive (HTML changing/generation/update).

#### Themes

There are many ways to theme your app. A good one is [Angular Boostrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) (from AngularUI). You can, than, use bootstrap js and css (with native bootstrap theming) and create amazing apps.

If you like Boostrap but you're looking into something more like Windows 8, you can use [BootMetro](http://aozora.github.io/bootmetro/).

If you're tired of Bootstrap, you can try [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) which looks really good.

Or you can google `front-end frameworks` and find your own.

But if you don't want to rely on 3rd party frameworks here, you can create your very own css rules. Just remember to keep them as clean as possible and to use SASS or LESS so you can avoid extra coding.

#### Charts

Take a look into [D3.js](http://d3js.org/). You can build amazing charts with that. If you're using Angular, try reading [this post on creating directives for D3](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html) or [these ready-to-use directives](https://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/).

#### Extra note

If you can try VS2015, than jump into AspNet 5 (MVC/WebApi). You'll have a better dev approach, cleaner framework, faster app and a relatively stable environment. You can use AspNet 5 (iis) or AspNet 5 core (which will enable your app to run from anywhere, including Linux/Mac, or from a pen-drive, with or without IIS installed).